# How can I mount software raid drive mdX with fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, gpt, raid5

I have raid5 configure with gpt partition to allow working with drive larger the 1.6 TB

Ubuntu version is 12.04 and the md drive is 5TB.

with:

```
mount -t ext3 /dev/md129 /images
```

mount works fine. But when I tried to put the same configuration to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/md129     /images     ext3     default   0   0
```

I get this error at boot:

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option ....

What I'm doing wrong or what I need to do to make it work?

Comment: FYI, the msdos partition table limit is 2 TiB, not 1.6 TB.

Answer (score 4):

You have "default" when it should be "defaults". You had a misspelling.

Answer (score 3):

add this line to your fstab

```
/dev/md129 /images ext3 noatime,rw 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Did u put your UUID in fstab? U can find your UUID when typing blkid in terminal

U see something like this:

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="HOME" UUID="6b9fc471-2752-455a-b402-fff7cea00145
```

Copy UUID to fstab:

```
UUID=6b9fc471-2752-455a-b402-fff7cea00145   /home    ext4          defaults       0       2
```